# Associative Numbers

Tags: binary-operations

Yesterday my friend wrote a number on a paper. He then added the number of ones in the binary representation of the number to that number and formed a new number. He kept doing the process infinitely. So he got a chain of numbers say A->B->C->D ...so on
    In this Chain B is said to be associated with A, C with A  & B both, D with A, B & C all and so on. He observed some relation in these numbers.
    Can anybody tell how are these numbers associated with each other?

Comment: your friend has infinitely too much time on his hands

Comment: ok.but there is some relation in these numbers obtained.I am not getting what is this.please tell me if you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence starting with $1$ is [OEIS sequence A010062](https://oeis.org/A010062).  You might look at the paper of [Stolarsky](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-059-01/S0002-9939-1976-0409340-X/home.html) and references therein.

Comment: Wow. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok....thank you so much :)